# fewer data values than degrees of freedom in loess

Tags: r, loess

when trying to perform a loess in R I'm getting the warning

```
1: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
  span too small.   fewer data values than degrees of freedom.
```

The fitted values obtained are identical (except first and last) to the observed values.
I feel however that as I'm using  a degree 2 regression I'd only need three points to fit a regression. As I have a span = 0.16 and 24 values, that would give 3.84 rounding up to 4, so more than enough.

```
ctg <- c(49L, 33L, 23L, 35L, 49L, 134L, 261L, 415L, 466L, 432L, 442L,  499L, 420L, 412L, 504L, 493L, 554L, 623L, 571L, 620L, 584L, 415L, 
329L, 193L)
span <-  0.16
h <- c(0, 1.04347826086957, 2.08695652173913, 3.1304347826087, 4.17391304347826, 
 5.21739130434783, 6.26086956521739, 7.30434782608696, 8.34782608695652, 
 9.39130434782609, 10.4347826086957, 11.4782608695652, 12.5217391304348, 
 13.5652173913043, 14.6086956521739, 15.6521739130435, 16.695652173913, 
 17.7391304347826, 18.7826086956522, 19.8260869565217, 20.8695652173913,
 21.9130434782609, 22.9565217391304, 24)
loess(ctg ~ h , span = span)
```